# How to use PersistentQueue in Reactor?

Tags: java, queue, project-reactor, chronicle-queue

I'm trying to configure [Reactor](https://github.com/reactor/reactor) to use [Chronicle](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Chronicle) based persistence, and I cannot find by information about this in documentation. I see two ways:

1. Create my own dispatcher supporting `PersistentQueue`
2. Use `EventBatcher` with such queue to wrap my `Reactor` instance

Which option is better? Or maybe there is another solution which I overlooked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reactor doesn't have persistence built into the Reactor object (which is why you're not finding documentation on it :).

If you're trying to persist the Events coming through for resiliency and replay purposes, you'll probably want to use the `EventBatcher`. The [test for `EventBatcher`](https://github.com/reactor/reactor/blob/master/reactor-core/src/test/groovy/reactor/core/spec/EventBatchersSpec.groovy#L54) has some code in it that shows how to combine an `Observable` and a `PersistentQueue`.

The option of writing your own `PersistentDispatcher` is certainly an interesting one. That path will be fraught with danger, though, as dispatching code is unforgiving when it comes to throughput. Even the smallest of changes can have drastic impacts on throughput. We've just re-written them as well to get more performance, so the latest code in master is different from the 1.0 release versions of the Dispatchers.

I wouldn't recommend taking the `Dispatcher` route right away, though. I'd try the `EventBatcher` first and only if that can't be used in your use case would I experiment with a custom `Dispatcher`. There are two new abstract base classes ([here](https://github.com/reactor/reactor/blob/master/reactor-core/src/main/java/reactor/event/dispatch/AbstractSingleThreadDispatcher.java) and [here](https://github.com/reactor/reactor/blob/master/reactor-core/src/main/java/reactor/event/dispatch/AbstractMultiThreadDispatcher.java)) to base new `Dispatcher` implementations on if you do decide to go that route.

Comment: Jon - I want to use Reactor as a persistent event bus in my application. As i understand EventBatcher works as a bag for events, which are being processed after invoking flush() method? With such requirements I understand that to implement reliable messaging it could be better to implement custom Dispatcher?